# How To send an Email from a client side angular form without server side application for Contact us form

Tags: angular, email, client, progressive-web-apps

I have an angular website (pwa website) without server side ( no database ) and I have a contact us form that I want to allow end user to send some data like "name","email","topic" and ... to a specific email like "info@gtx.com"

Currently I uploaded the website without contact us form on a Host domain.

I'm using angular 7 for the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not send email directly through front end code. 
Instead you can

- use end users mail client.
- use a thrid party web service.
- use your own back end service.

(You can put the back end code in the same application and host it as one application. https://nodemailer.com/about/ is a lib for sending mail using back end js code)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently this service called [FormSpree](https://formspree.io/), which allows us to handle email contact forms without the need for server-side code. It has been working decently well, even up till now.

1) You can handle it purely on your component.html, after specifying the `name` attribute and adding the POST request url on your form's `action` attribute.

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/your@email.com" method="POST" />
.
.
<input type="text" name="name">
```

2) Or, you can handle it on your component.ts/service.ts by calling HttpClient to send a post request to 'https://formspree.io/your@email.com', together with the request body and headers.

---

Alternatively, you may want to use SendGrid, though I may not be of much help here, since I have not actually tried it. However, they seem to have a pretty extensive API and decent [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started/#send-your-email-using-the-api), so you may want to refer to that on how to get started with it.

Comment: @Ali There is a free tier. You should open up the link and see!

Answer (score 0):

What i did was used an email api (mailthis.to) with a postmessage inside the service to send an email. and it works